# Puppet master wont allow sign puppet agent certificate request, saying "Could not resolve x.x.x.x: no name for x.x.x.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have a puppet-master puppet agent setup in AWS VPC. The system has been running for the last 2 years without too many issues, but today the master will not accept a certificate request from any of the agents once they are launched saying `"Could not resolve x.x.x.x: no name for x.x.x.x"`

The puppet master is specified in the puppet.conf for the agent. I can see in the logs for the master that the agent does in face reach, but the master "rejects" and does not sign a certificate from an instance in a subnet which it usually accepts. Ive also tried to remove the certs from the master running "puppet cert clean ip-x-x-x-x.ap-in..." and re trying manually from the agent. The agent tries to connect and then says `"Exiting;no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled"`

Comment: Check that time is configured properly in the puppet-master server.

Comment: I checked the time with the `date` command and it seems to be fine.